# Ошибка vk.auth()

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, обработка-ошибок

Не  работает функция vk.auth()Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Egor/PycharmProjects/Domashka/MyBot.py", line 4, in <module>
    vk.auth()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\PycharmProjects\Domashka\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 159, in auth
    raise LoginRequired('Login is required to auth')
vk_api.exceptions.LoginRequired: Login is required to auth
```

Не знаю что делать.Посмотрел урок ,там все работает.У меня- нет.Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам явно написали: Login is required to auth . "Для авторизации требуется логин".

Comment: import vk_api
import time
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='231b61671d9b12aa8815aac64753f8df1f2a911fef7654ff036ccb4a49c5c013d3c0faaebfc891183e926')
vk.auth()
values={'out':0,'count':100,'time_offset':60}
vk.method('messages.get',values)


def message_S(user_id, s):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'messages': s})

Comment: import vk_api
import time
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='231b61671d9b12aa8815aac64753f8df1f2a911fef7654ff036ccb4a49c5c013d3c0faaebfc891183e926')
vk.auth()
values={'out':0,'count':100,'time_offset':60}
vk.method('messages.get',values)


def message_S(user_id, s):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'messages': s})

А где его взять?

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev а где его взять?Видимо я смотрю старые уроки.

Comment: @Egor, зайдите под своей страницей, например